# How can I display xeyes on a remote host without using SSH?

Tags: x11

I have X running on two machines - astra (slackware 15), and nebula (macos mojave). I would like to run xeyes locally on astra, and have it display on nebula. My understanding from various documents is that I should be able to run:

```
xeyes -display nebula:X.Y
```

from astra, where X is the display index on nebula, and Y is the screen number.

I have tried many combinations of X and Y, and no X or Y, etc. to no avail. I keep getting the error message:

> Error: Can't open display: nebula:X.Y

I am able to display X programs running on the remote machines, locally using:

```
ssh -Y host
```

with no issues, but this is not the problem I'm trying to solve. I want to be able to run my local clients, locally, and have the display appear remotely, as described above and as supported by the Xorg server.

There may be a difference between how this used to work and how it works now, the documentation I'm finding is older.

Comment: IIRC for security reasons Xorg is usually configured to run with option `-nolisten tcp` which means it only provides a local Unix socket

Comment: @steeldriver Even if the X display was listening you would still need xauth credentials or run `xhost +` (never a good idea).

Comment: Isn't the less wide open version something like `xhost +astra`, @doneal24? It's been a long time and I'm hazy on the details

Comment: @steeldriver's comment pointed the way to the answer.

Comment: @roaima I'm hazy on the auth options as well, that's why I didn't attempt an answer - glad the OP got it figured out! One would hope they are doing this behind a NAT/firewall that doesn't allow arbitrary connections to :6000 + N as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display on nebula, the MacOS Mojave machine, from astra, the Slackware 15 machine, requires a handful of steps:

1. In XQuartz preferences - Security->Allow connections from network clients.
2. Restart XQuartz
3. Obtain the MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 from nebula
4. Add it to astra's xauth list
5. Run the client from astra and it will display on nebula's screen

Here are the details:

To see how X was started, run `ps aux | grep X`:

```
user            96691   0.0  0.0  4279568   5012   ??  S    12:39PM   0:00.01 /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz :0 -nolisten tcp -iglx -auth /Users/user/.serverauth.96532
```

The key point to note, is the `-nolisten tcp` and `-auth`. These indicate respectively, that the X server isn't listening on TCP and that connections to the X server require authentication.

Changing the preferences in XQuartz to allow network connections and restarting it result in the following change:

```
user            97993   0.0  0.0  4279568   5004   ??  S     2:08PM   0:00.01 /opt/X11/bin/Xquartz :0 -listen tcp -iglx -auth /Users/user/.serverauth.97835
```

Now, XQuartz is listening on TCP, as indicated by `-listen tcp`

To obtain the magic auth cookie from nebula, on nebula, or via remote login, run `xauth list` and find the correct cookie:

```
nebula:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  240800a1f435f70d92f8f8c706eeb547
```

On astra, add the cookie to the xauth list, using:

```
xauth add nebula:0 . 240800a1f435f70d92f8f8c706eeb547
```

If all went well, you should now be able to run xeyes from astra:

```
xeyes -display nebula:0
```

[image: xeyes]

Things to watch out for:

1. XQuartz needs to be running :)
2. The cookie needs to be up to date. It will change.
3. There is a dot in the `xauth add` command that is required.